# Polymorphism in Objective-C - iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, delegates, polymorphism

I have been using Polymorphism in C++ for a long time now and I rather like using it. Does Objective-C have this functionality? Maybe has something to do with Delegates?

I have been playing around with iOS development for a while and have been using Frameworks such as MessageUI and iAd.

So when I import these types of frameworks and then use their methods like this one for example:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                    error:(NSError*)error;
```

Does that mean I am essentially using Polymorphism in Objective-C?

Comment: Polymorphism is when you have an instance of a class and use it as an instance of a parent class. You use it when you subclass something or implement a protocol.

Comment: Couldn't you have just checked the Wikipedia article?

Comment: Find a good tutorial for Objective-C.  (It kinda looks like you don't understand polymorphism in C++ either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the word Polymorphism means many forms.

Polymorphism in general is very broad topic and basically it invokes lot of things like method overloading, operator overloading, inheritance, reusability.

And I don't think I implement polymorphism, rather I use the specific term like inheritance, operator overloading, method overloading e.t.c.

Objective-C polymorphism means that a call to a member function will cause a different function to be executed depending on the type of object that invokes the function.

For example -

I have a base class `Shape`, defined as-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Shape : NSObject {

    CGFloat area;
}

- (void)printArea;
- (void)calculateArea;
@end

@implementation Shape

- (void)printArea {
    NSLog(@"The area is %f", area);
}

- (void)calculateArea {
}

@end
```

I have derived two base classes `Square` and `Rectangle` from `Shape` as -

```
@interface Square : Shape { 

    CGFloat length;
}

- (id)initWithSide:(CGFloat)side;

- (void)calculateArea;

@end

@implementation Square

- (id)initWithSide:(CGFloat)side {
    length = side;
    return self;
}

- (void)calculateArea {
    area = length * length;
}

- (void)printArea {
    NSLog(@"The area of square is %f", area);
}

@end

@interface Rectangle : Shape {

    CGFloat length;
    CGFloat breadth;
}

- (id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)rLength andBreadth:(CGFloat)rBreadth;

@end

@implementation Rectangle

- (id)initWithLength:(CGFloat)rLength andBreadth:(CGFloat)rBreadth {
    length = rLength;
    breadth = rBreadth;
    return self;
}

- (void)calculateArea {
    area = length * breadth;
}

@end
```

Now the calling method on any object will invoke the method of the corresponding class as-

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Shape *square = [[Square alloc]initWithSide:10.0];
    [square calculateArea];
    [square printArea];
    Shape *rect = [[Rectangle alloc]
    initWithLength:10.0 andBreadth:5.0];
    [rect calculateArea];
    [rect printArea];        
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

And as you asked about

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
      error:(NSError*)error;
```

the above method is the delegate method of `MFMailComposeViewController` class and yes as it is implemented by the delegate implementer, so it can have the customized implementation as per the requirements within the legal guidelines and so it's also a form of polymorphism(as the delegate method could be implemented in more than one way).

Comment: this is just an example there could be other sub uses of polymorphisms as well.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, your answer has been very helpful indeed :)